# ajax form submitting but calling error function

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc

This is a simple form which takes 2 dates from and to and I am submiiting those to values to server.

```
<form action="#" method="get">
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from"  name="fromDate">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to"  name="toDate">

 <input type="button" value="Recv Amount" id="recv">
 </form>
```

and the following is the controller code

```
@RequestMapping("getPayments")
@ResponseBody
public void getPayments(HttpServletRequest request,Model uiModel)
{
    String toDate=request.getParameter("toDate");
    String fromDate=request.getParameter("fromDate");
    System.out.println(fromDate+" "+ toDate);
}
```

and this is js code

```
$('#recv').click(function(){
      var fromDate=$('#from').val();
      var toDate=$('#to').val();
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET", 
           url: url,  
              data:{"fromDate":fromDate,"toDate":toDate},
              dataType:"json",

         success: function( data ) {
             console.log('success');


         },
         error:function()
         {
             console.log('failed');
         }
        }); 
  });
```

when ever I hit the button I can see todate and from date in the server console (This means System.out.println(fromDate+" "+ toDate); is executed) but in the browser console failed is printed(this means  console.log('failed'); is executed)

I do not have any error in  browser console but the success function of ajax is never executed.

What could be the reason behind it?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47k04rsb/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are waiting for a JSON answer, but you are not returning anything. jQuery is going to give you an error. Remove 'dataType' from your ajax request or return a valid json object.

From jQuery documentation:

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

[jQuery ajax query](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Based on the information provided issue is that data is expected the way you formed your success parameter.
Since no data is returned (void method) it won't actually do anything.

Therefore you need to use:

```
statusCode: { 200: function() { alert( "success" ); } }
```

Remove success and error as success won't work (no data being returned) and error will display (simply because no data is returned) and replace them with relevant status codes.

Comment: sorry for the type mistake,I am doing get method in ajax and so I am not wrting in controller method = RequestMethod.Get

Comment: so only place it doesn't show it is in Console? have you tried doing alert("success") to see whether it hits the success?

Comment: yes,success function in ajax is never calling.I created another method,another form,another input field and tested.But still the same

Comment: change your success to following code  statusCode: {
200: function() {
alert( "success" );
}
}

Comment: when i tried your way it alerts success and also in the console failed is displayed.Whats the wrong now?

Comment: your answer is also useful,so +1.If you think my question will be useful for future then you also give me +1